# I want to play minecraft

Tags: software-installation, software-center, java

I can't install anything from the Ubuntu Software Center.

For example, I tried to install Java but I couldn't and don't say to install it off Google; I have tried installing Java from Google but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's how I did it:
>
> Install java 8 separately, without messing with system java:

1. Download the latest jdk 8 .tar.gz from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
2. Extract the .tar.gz to **/opt/java**:

   $ sudo mkdir -p /opt/java
   $ sudo tar -C /opt/java -xzf Downloads/jdk-8[tab]
3. Create a link to the java executable:

   $ sudo ln -s /opt/java/jdk1.8[tab]/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java8

> Minecraft:

1. Download the latest Minecraft.jar from [Mojang](https://minecraft.net/download).
2. Start Minecraft:

   $ java8 -jar Downloads/Minecraft.jar
3. Once Minecraft has started, select "Lock to Launcher" in the launcher to create a persistent Minecraft launcher.

> For extra credit, create a script:

1. Type in the following commands:

   $ mkdir -p ~/bin
   $ cat > ~/bin/minecraft
2. Type in script payload:

   #! /bin/sh
   java8 -jar ~/Downloads/Minecraft.jar
3. Press Control+D to signal end of file.
4. Make script executable:

   $ chmod +x bin/minecraft

> , and a desktop entry:

1. Type in the following command:

   $ cat > ~/.local/share/applications/minecraft.desktop
2. Type in desktop file payload:

   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Minecraft
   Icon=Pictures/minecraft.png
   Exec=minecraft
   StartupNotify=false
3. Press Control+D to signal end of file.
4. Find a suitable minecraft icon image.
5. Copy image to **Pictures/** (assuming .png format):

   $ cp *PathToImageFile.png* Pictures/minecraft.png

> Now you can start Minecraft with the command  "minecraft". The launcher should show the minecraft icon you copied to **Pictures/**. As before, select "Lock to Launcher" to persist your launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I know why you are having difficulty installing anything directly from the software center.  I can only assume that you are operating from a standard, which is to say, not administrator account.  This often happens when someone trusts their relative or friend to install Ubuntu for them, and that other person issues the newbie a less-than-administrator account simply trying to keep them out of trouble.  In such a case, the terminal won't work for you either, so don't even try that.

So, long story short, you first need to get into the administrative account, or persuade your installer to upgrade you to an administrator (or perhaps get your own computer if you are using his/hers)

Ordinarily the software center is the safest way to install anything under ubuntu.  I would never advise you (or anyone else) to install it off google.  There seems to be a popular view on this site that all software must be installed from the command line.  I realize that's the legacy of linux, but not one anyone should feel compelled to follow.

There are two legit ways I'm aware of to install the real, original, pay-for version of minecraft under ubuntu, and I believe only one of them requires installing the windows emulator.  The windows emulator can be entirely installed through the software center and I can walk you through that, but in this case I'm not convinced that's necessarily the better way.

Your other two alternatives are easy and won't cost you a cent, although you will still need administrative privileges.  Under the Ubuntu Software Center you have two free versions of minecraft-like games.  I believe they are called MineTest and MyCraft.  From what I've read of the former, it offers some options not offered in the original game.  It also has the benefit that you can persuade your friends to sign up without incurring expense for them.